# How to make the visible binding to work

Tags: knockout.js

I'm experimenting with Knockout.js, and can't make the `visible` binding to work in the following code when returning an empty array (here's its [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8u2sxrge/3/)):

```js
$(document).ready()
{
    BuildFactoryGrid();
}

function BuildFactoryGrid ()
{
    var factoryViewModel = new FactoryViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(factoryViewModel);
    factoryViewModel.init();
}

function FactoryViewModel ()
{
    var self = this;
    self.FactoryRecords = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.FactoryRecordsLength = ko.computed(function ()
    {
        return self.FactoryRecords().length;
    });

    self.init = function ()
    {
        self.FactoryRecords(GetFactoryData());
    };
}

function GetFactoryData ()
{
    var objArr =   
    [
      {
        District: 1, 
        Department: 22,
        Team: 33
      },
      {
        District: 1, 
        Department: 24,
        Team: 35
      },
      {
        District: 2, 
        Department: 54,
        Team: 9
      },
    ];
    return objArr;
    // return []; // remove comment to return an empty array
}
```

```css
tr>th, td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th></th>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Team</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: FactoryRecords">
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: District"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Department"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Team"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-bind="visible: $parent.FactoryRecordsLength() == 0 ">
            <td colspan="4">No Records</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When returning an empty array, the "No Records" `span` should appear, but it doesn't. Be glad to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "No Records" block is nested within a `foreach` binding, which will not be drawn if there are no records to loop over. You'll have to move the "No Records" out of the foreach binding context, and to do that you'll want to move your `foreach` to a virtual element instead of the `<tbody>` element.

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-bind="visible: FactoryRecordsLength() == 0 ">
      <td colspan="4">No Records</td>
    </tr>
  <!--ko foreach: FactoryRecords-->
    <tr> 
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: District"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Department"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Team"></td>
    </tr>
    <!--/ko-->
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *visible* binding "doesn't work", because you using it inside *foreach*. And since your *FactoryRecords* that binded to *foreach* have no element - no elements won't be generated and your *visible* binding won't be ever called.

Just fix you markup and separate foreach and default row:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="active">
      <th></th>
      <th>District</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Team</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Foreach generate elements if they are exists -->
    <!-- ko foreach: FactoryRecords -->
    <tr> 
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: District"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Department"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Team"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- If no elements present - create our row with message -->
    <tr data-bind="visible: FactoryRecordsLength() === 0 ">
      <td colspan="4">No Records</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
return objArr;
// return []; // remove comment to return an empty array
```

The array will be populated and `FactoryRecordsLength().length` will be 3

If you do

```
//return objArr;
 return []; // remove comment to return an empty array
```

The foreach binding will have nothing to display and you will not see anything in your table at all.

Ideally you should add another record to your object to determine if there are records, for example:

```
var objArr =   
[
  {
    District: 1, 
    Department: 22,
    Team: 33,
    Records: 0
  },
  {
    District: 1, 
    Department: 24,
    Team: 35,
    Records: 1
  },
  {
    District: 2, 
    Department: 54,
    Team: 9,
    Records: 0
  },
];
```